# How to ignore quotation marks when concatenating

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Background: I am creating a table which updates daily with a count of our data loads across a schema. Every day I need it to create a new column, then populate that column with the count. When I go to add the count in I get a Syntax error: unexpected '';''. (line 68). This is due to the quotation marks around date in the WHERE table_name = 'DATE' part. How do I get Snowflake to ignore these quotation marks?

```
DECLARE
alter_table_add string;
column_name string;
column_data_type string;
add_date string;
sql string;
BEGIN
    SELECT 'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD ' INTO :alter_table_add;
    SELECT 'C_' || TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') INTO :column_name;
    SELECT ' VARCHAR' INTO :column_data_type;
    SELECT 'UPDATE MY_TABLE SET ' || :column_name || ' = GETDATE() ' || 'WHERE table_name = 'DATE';' INTO :add_date;
    --SELECT :alter_table_add || :column_name || :column_data_type || add_date INTO :sql;
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (:sql);
    RETURN add_date;
END;
```

(Yes I will have the date both in the column name and in the first row. Date in column name is for tracking, date in the row is a complete time stamp of when the count was made. The next part of the code would be doing the count and inserting that into the next row in the column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ANSI SQL way to denote a string literal is to surround it in single quotes, and the standard way to escape a *literal* single quote in a string is to use two single quotes.  The troublesome line may be written as:

```sql
SELECT 'UPDATE MY_TABLE SET ' || :column_name || ' = GETDATE() ' ||
    'WHERE table_name = ''DATE'';' INTO :add_date;
```

As a side note, rather than using dynamic SQL to update your table you might want to find some way to do a direct update.

Comment: I knew it'd be an simple fix - thank you for your help! I shall look into direct update as well